# PDF direct to blockchain?

Tags: solidity, transactions, data

So firstly I'm just going to preface this with the disclaimer that this is an educational exercise, I understand that the gas fees would be ridiculous. This is for a project, not to ever deploy to mainnet.

So basically I want to give users the option to upload a PDF to IFPS AND the option to pay the insane gas fee to upload a PDF directly within the transaction data. My code for the "direct to blockchain" option will not work and I'm kinda going crazy trying to figure it out....

I'm going to post the section of python for the streamlit side and my solidity code. Basically if I directly feed it the byte data for the word "hello" it will transact fine, but if I convert a blank pdf with just the word "hello" to byte data in python its getting rejected with this error:

"ContractLogicError: execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert"

I am deploying this through remix IDE on a ganache local testnet.

Relevant Solidity Code:

```
mapping(address => bytes) public pdfDocuments;

function payForService(uint256 amount, bytes memory pdfData) 
public payable {
    require(msg.value >= amount, "Insufficient payment provided");
    // Store the PDF data (you can modify this based on your 
storage needs):
    // Example: Mapping to store multiple PDFs
pdfDocuments[msg.sender] = pdfData;
payable(address(0x56c31FF8a66e7aDCF370Fa0eA723056E61d55Bc6)).transfer(msg.value);

    emit ServicePayment(msg.sender, msg.value); // Emit event for tracking
}
```

Relevant Python Code:

```py
if upload_options == "Upload Title Blockchain":
    choice = options_database[upload_options][0]
    choice_cost = options_database[upload_options][1]

    value = 0
    # file_bytes = uploaded_file.read()
    bytes_string = uploaded_file.read()
    # data = file_bytes.hex()
    print(bytes_string)
    st.write("## Option Types, and Cost")
    st.write(choice)
    if bytes_string is not None and uploaded_file is not None and initial_sale_value != "":
        estimated_gas = w3.eth.estimate_gas({
            'from': address,
            'to': contract_address,
            "value": 0,
            'data': bytes_string, # The data field should be the hex string
            # Add other necessary transaction fields
        })
        transaction_value_BLOC = estimated_gas * 2 
        st.write(transaction_value_BLOC)

        if st.button("Register Title"):
            tx_hash = contract.functions.payForService(
                amount=transaction_value_BLOC, 
                pdfData=bytes_string
            ).transact({'from': address, 'value': transaction_value_BLOC})
            receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
            receipt_dict = dict(receipt)
            st.write(receipt_dict)
```

Please help! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is every struggling with this, I did find my own solution. You need to use the Ganache CLI NOT the GUI. Not entirely sure why this makes it work but it does...